# Is there a way to return a view from controller by his route name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have on my web.php this route

```
Route::get('/manager/posts/create', 'PostController@index')->name('createArticle');
```

is there a way to call this route from controller on return view instead of his route `return view('manager.posts.crear');`

something like `return view('createArticle')`?

Comment: Redirect to that route maybe? `return redirect()->route('createArricle');`

Comment: You can go with Davit answer, but remember to rename your blade templates, or move them to appropriate folders

Comment: return redirect()->route('createArricle'); works, but is there any difference doing a redirect instead of returning a view? @Qirel

Comment: They do different things. One servers the view, one is routed through the controller fist, then severed the views through there

Comment: Lazy Cristian :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for named routes:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

```php
return redirect()->route('createArticle');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


public function index(Request $request)
{
    $routeName  = Route::currentRouteName();
    // or $routeName = $request->route()->getName();
    return view($routeName);
}
```

Comment: @Cristian I think, you are looking for something similer to `Davit` ans.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for [view routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#view-routes).

Comment: No, that's not what OP asked for